# determine the correct repository to add for a specific package

Tags: 12.04, add-apt-repository

I'd like to install https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-do/0.9-1build1 using package-manager/apt-get.

How can I determine which repository to add to install this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to build gnome-do from source or just install it? (The package you link to is a source package for Quantal (12.10)

Comment: Yes, you are both right. I select AMD64, then I dl the .deb. Can't believe I didn't see that! Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You can just download the deb package from there, just select the architecture for your system, and if you click on overview you can see where is the package located, *universe*.